# How to instantly redirect all the 404 links to the homepage in a basic HTML site?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, http, browser

Instead of having a custom 404 link not found page, how can we have the clients instantly redirect to the homepage if the link is broken in a basic HTML website?

**EDIT:** My site is a plain HTML website with 5 pages, hosted on GoDaddy. No server side configuration, just HTML and little CSS and JS.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information for us to help you. Where/how is this site hosted? Does it have a backend? Do you have a custom 404 page already?

Comment: My site is a plain HTML website with 5 pages, hosted on GoDaddy. No server side configuration, just HTML and little CSS and JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just have a static site, the simplest way to do this is with a .htaccess file. You can redirect 404s to your homepage with this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

Comment: Defiantly the shortest, fastest and therefor best solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default HTML redirect syntax in the head of the error 404 page : `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://yourwebsite.com/homepage.html">`

Comment: Yes. But I want to redirect **only** if the user goes to a page url that doesn't exist within my domain.

Comment: Your host service doesn't provide you the option to set a custom 404 error page?